# How to get a list of movies sorted by popularity (favourited by most users) in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have following schema for a movie api project.

```
var MovieSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    genre: {
        type: String
    },
    release_date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    }
});
const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 6 },
    favourite_movies: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Movie"
    }]
});
```

Please note that schema is hard to change because of other feature restrictions of project.

How to get a list of all movies sorted by popularity (favourited by most users) for this schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the aggregate pipeline for this. Can try something like

```js
MovieModel.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "users", // user collection name
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "favourite_movies",
        as: "user",
      },
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        count: { $size: "$user" },
      },
    },
    {
      $sort: { count: -1 },
    },
    {
      $unset: ["user", "count"],
    },
  ],
  (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(data);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be in your router, not in Mongoose. Mongoose is used to adhere a standard when writing to the database, not receiving information from it.

It will likely end up being something like this.

```
movieRouter
    .route("/")
    .get((req, res, next) => {
        Movie.find()
            .then((movies) => {
                res.statusCode = 200;
                res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                res.json(movies);
            })
            .catch((err) => next(err));
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to get movies in sorted order by popularity.

Comment: Sure. Once you have the returned object of movies you can pipe it into a function that sorts the object on the popularity key.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. But I have to decide the popularity from the field favourite_movies in userSchema. How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If the MongoDB document already exists you will need to connect to it and get the object list to see what fields there are. Then you can filter or sort on the available fields.

But Mongoose will only help you structure how you write to the database. Not read from it.